# TinyMCE and Dynamics365

Tags: tinymce, microsoft-dynamics

I have a TinyMCE editor working with Dynamics365.  In it, I'm able to get images to copy and paste into the window.  However, I'm wondering where these images get posted to and/or stored and what I need to do to bring them back up when the page is closed and reopened.

When I reopen the page I get a list of errors saying the images can't be found (makes sense).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you copy and paste the image into TinyMCE what actual HTML are you getting before you save the content?  What plugins are you loading in TinyMCE to help facilitate the copy/paste?  There is a free `paste` plugin and a commercial `powerpaste` plugin - these would typically result in slightly different HTML depending on the source of what you are copying.

Knowing what sort of HTML you get after the paste would be the first step in determining possible solutions.

Comment: Hi, I figured out what I needed to make it work.  I just reference the images as URLs and don't worry about uploading them.  We are using an older version so this facilitates the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

We are using URLs for inserting the images into the page.